# xslt select only elements with a given value

Tags: xslt

This is my input:

```
<div class="z">zzz
  <div class="a">a1</div>
  <div class="b">b1
    <div class="c">b1c1
      <div class="d">b1c1d1</div>
      <div class="e">b1c1e1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c1f1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">b1c2
      <div class="d">b1c2d1</div>
      <div class="e">b1c2e1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c2f1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c2f2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">b2
    <div class="c">b2c1
      <div class="d">b2c1d1</div>
      <div class="e">b2c1e1</div>
      <div class="e">b2c1e2</div>
      <div class="f">b2c1f1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the output I would like to get:

```
<div class="z">zzz
  <div class="a">a1</div>
  <div class="b">b1
    <div class="c">b1c1
      <div class="d">b1c1d1</div>
      <div class="e">b1c1e1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c1f1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">b1c2
      <div class="d">b1c2d1</div>
      <div class="e">b1c2e1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c2f1</div>
      <div class="f">b1c2f2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

that is I would like to get:

- any text for div class="z", ie "zzz"
- any child that has class != "b"
- any child that has class="b" and value = "b1"

I am using the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- Identity template, copies everything as is -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='z']">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='b' and text()='b1']" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but unfortunately my output is empty :(

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue you have is that the text node for "b1" also contains whitespace. The "b1" is followed by a line feed and some spaces, and this is why your current check on the text node is failing. To cater for this, you can use the `normalize-space` function which will trim the whitespace from the ends (it will also combine multiple whitespace characters in the middle of the text to a single space, should any be present)

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='b' and normalize-space(text())='b1']" />
```

This will at least give you some output, but you will also find the "z" class div is not appearing in the output. This is because having matched the div, you have to then explicitly copy the node to the output, along with all the child nodes and attributes too. Currently you are just selecting divs with a class of "b", and not anything else.

Therefore, your `xsl:apply-templates` should really look like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|text()|div[(@class='b' and normalize-space(text())='b1') or @class != 'b']" />
```

However, you can view the problem from a different perspective. Instead of writing rules for what you want to copy, write the rules for what you don't want to copy, and create templates to ignore such nodes. The identity template takes care of copying everything you do want.

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- Identity template, copies everything as is -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='b' and normalize-space(text())!='b1']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oh, that makes it simpler. Thank you Tim.